# Why is Resource.Designer.cs not created

Tags: xamarin.android

I created a class library (Mono for Android) and put the folders Resources/Drawable, Resources/Layout and Resources/Values in it.

Unfortunately the file Resource.Designer.cs is not created automatically. I've all xml-Files set on BuildAction "AndroidResource"... but no recource file is created.

DO I have to do something else?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't support for resources in a class library project.  Resources must be in the main application project.

Comment: For those finding this question via search: Resources in class lib projects are now supported in Mono for Andoid 4.4 and later. See http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/mono_for_android_4/mono_for_android_4.4